# How to enforce script, template and style tags order in vue with linter

Tags: vue.js, eslint, lint

I want to add a linter rule that checks that the tags are in this order: `<script>`, `<template>` and `<style>`.
Vue's default is `<template>` first, but I want the `<script>` because I consider it more important.

It'd be awesome that this could be auto-fixed.

I couldn’t find this rule for eslint, and if there isn't any I may consider creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eslint-plugin-vue` supports the [`component-tags-order`  rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/component-tags-order.html) for this. It's already included in `"plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"` and `"plugin:vue/recommended"` rule sets (if using a Vue CLI scaffolded project).

The config to enforce `<script>`, `<template>`, and then `<style>`:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'vue/component-tags-order': ['error', {
      order: [ 'script', 'template', 'style' ]
    }],
  }
}
```

Note the rule does **not** implement auto-fixing, so you'll only get linter errors.

However, there's a command-line utility ([`v-change-tags-order`](https://github.com/kawamataryo/v-change-tags-order)) that you could run to rearrange the tags:

```sh
npx v-change-tags-order
```

Comment: @MauriciAbad Evan You just [tweeted](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1427982990957846529) about a new utility that rearranges the tag order. See updated answer.